# PHP Command to Calculate Percentage of MySQL rows

Tags: php, mysql

Firstly, I am new to PHP so I'm still learning. I have a PHP program to display a count of rows on MySQL which frequently changes. This is the echo I am using to display count and percentages -

```
echo"<tr><td>{$row['Name']}</td><td {$row['COUNT(tag_logs.tag_no)']}/75</td><td>{$row['(COUNT(tag_logs.tag_no)']}%</td></tr>
```

The first count function works just fine. For the second iteration of...

```
{$row['(COUNT(tag_logs.tag_no)']}%
```

...I would like to divide the count by 75 and multiply by 100.

I have tried assigning 75 to a string, such as -

```
$perc = 75;
```

I also tried a few variations to carry out division only -

```
{$row['(COUNT(tag_logs.tag_no)'/75]}%

{$row['(COUNT(tag_logs.tag_no)'/$perc]}%
```

However, I've had little luck as I'm unsure about where to plug in the variable. This is the error I receive -

> Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in
>   /Library/WebServer/Documents/count.php on line 16

Comment: What was wrong with the answer I gave to the question you subsequently deleted?

Comment: Apologies since I don't exactly remember you answering my question in particular. Would you mind reminding me of your previous answer?

Comment: I have reposted my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to divide the value you are reading outside the quoted string. Try this:

```
echo "<tr><td>{$row['Name']}</td><td>{$row['COUNT(tag_logs.tag_no)']}</td><td>" . round($row['COUNT(tag_logs.tag_no)'] / 75 * 100, 2) . "%</td></tr>";
```

I would also suggest that you rewrite your query with an alias on the `COUNT` e.g.

```
COUNT(tag_logs.tag_no) AS tag_cnt
```

so that you can just refer to it as `$row['tag_cnt']` instead of `$row['COUNT(tag_logs.tag_no)']`. This will also save you time if you change the expression in the query later as you won't have to change the PHP as well.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I apologize about not getting around to responding the last time. If you wouldn't mind, could you very briefly explain what I did wrong in my initial code?

Comment: @OloOlo no worries. The problem with your original code was that you were doing everything inside the quoted string, and you have to do math outside quotes. Enclosing something in `{}` inside a quoted string only works for variables.